# Select Query in Linq

Tags: linq

I am very new in Linq, I want to select two columns of table. Please tell me how can I write a query for that?

I want to fill dropdown list.

Thanks
Manoj

Comment: You need to provide us with much, much more info than that, Manoj. What does your table definition look like? Are you using linq to sql, linq to datasets, linq to entities or some other provider? What language are you in, what version of .net? What is this dropdown list you're talking about? What have you got so far?

Comment: I am using Linq to Sql and i was just binding ddl and i want to write query to get value from sql 2005 table and bind into sql .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var query = from u in users
            select new {u.Name, u.LastName}
```

Comment: I think this is missing the "new" keyword for selecting/creating an anonymous type.

Answer (score 0):

Usually its something like:

```
        using (var ctx = new EntityName())
        {
            var query = ctx.TableName.Select(o => new { o.Col1, o.Col2 });
        }
```